# EXEC master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb error when looping through databases

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following the error when executing the statement:

```
EXEC master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 
    'INSERT INTO AuditDatabase.dbo.[DataDictionary] 
         exec sp_get_extendedproperty use [?] "?"'

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'master'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'tempdb'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'model'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'msdb'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'AdventureWorks2014'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'TestDatabase'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'AuditDatabase'.
```

If I run it without the use syntax like this:

```
EXEC master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 
    'INSERT INTO AuditDatabase.dbo.[DataDictionary] 
        exec sp_get_extendedproperty "?"'
```

It only loops through the AdventureWorks2014 and msdb databases. It does not loop through any other database.

sp_get_extendedproperty is on master db.

Comment: Note: `sp_MSforeachdb` is notoriously unreliable. See: https://sqlblog.org/2018/10/22/sp-ineachdb-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use statement is in the wrong place. Try something like this:
I
   exec sp_MSforeachdb 'use ? rest of statement here  '

I just executed this and it worked fine:

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 'use ? select * from sys.objects;'
```

If your proc is name sp_xxx and is in master it should be available in all databases.

Comment: I got the same errors as before on every database name: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near 'TestDatabase'.